# MoPub integration with Android Studio and LibGDX

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, mopub

After reading some people talk about how you can suddenly get banned from AdMob I decided to look into other ad networks and MoPub with their mediation looks like a good option.

For the past few hours I've been trying to get it to import into my project for which I use Android Studio and LibGDX, the instructions on their site are only for Eclipse and from Googling I haven't found a solution that works with Android Studio and LibGDX.

I tried a lot of things, but after hours of failing I decided to ask it here, all I have after today is the mopub-sdk folder in the libs folder of the android project. Is it possible to use MoPub with LibGDX or should I find an alternative?

I'm looking forward to your answers and thanks in advance!

Cheers.